# How do I handle priority and propagation in an event system?

Tags: design, object-oriented, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

Let's say I have a simple event system with the following syntax:

```
object = new Object();
object.bind("my_trigger", function()  { print "hello"; });
object.bind("my_trigger", function()  { print "hello2"; });
object.trigger("my_trigger");
```

How could I make sure hello2 is printed out first? (I do not want my code to depend on which order the events were bind).

On top of that, how would I prevent my events from propagating? (e.g. I want to stop every other event from being executed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend priority queues in a producer/consumer setup.

edit:
I've used priority queues in sort of a pub/sub system before. I set up a router object; a method of that object was a sender, with the priority and destination point specified. There was a reader method which would be the destination point. 
Under the hood would be priority queues. The router object would handle reading and writing the queues.

It was actually a multithreaded system; the producers of information would be things like a http server, files, etc, the consumers could be the windows event queue, files, or http messages. The router would handle the messaging between the producers and consumers.

For filtering, I would determine who cares about the filtering, and place the filter block as part of that element.  Possibly each element (producer, router, and consumer) would get the capability to hook. (e.g., a list of functions passed in and `AND`'d together to allow a message to pass).

Comment: @Peeter: see update for further thoughts

Comment: I took your thoughts into count and this is what I managed to produce: https://github.com/peeter-tomberg/php-events

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking a chain-like design would be sufficient.

Here is a quick example of what I'm trying to describe, in Scala.

```
object Main extends App {

  // Event 1 - Prints Hello and doesn't break the chain
  val event1 = new Event {
    override def trigger = { println("Hello"); continue }
  }

  // Event 2 - Prints Hello2 but breaks the chain
  val event2 = new Event {
    override def trigger = { println("Hello2"); stop }
  }

  // Create new EventChain
  val eventChain = new EventChain

  // Add event1, then event2 at the beginning
  eventChain.addFirst(event1).addFirst(event2)

  // Bind the event chain to the identifier
  EventManager.bind("my_trigger", eventChain)

  // Trigger a new event
  EventManager.trigger("my_trigger")
}

object EventManager {

  // Keeps track of trigger bindings
  var events = Map[String, EventChain]()

  // Binds a trigger
  def bind(id: String, chain: EventChain) {
    events += ((id, chain))
  }

  // Triggers an EventChain
  def trigger(id: String) {
    events.find(e => e._1 == id) match {
      case Some(event) => event._2.trigger
      case None =>
    }
  }
}

// An event
abstract class Event {
  // Your response here
  def trigger: Boolean;

  // To continue
  def continue = true

  // To break the chain
  def stop = false
}

class EventChain {
  // List of Events
  private var events = List[Event]()

  // Adds an event to the beginning
  def addFirst(event: Event) = {
    events ::= event
    this
  }

  // Triggers the EventChain
  def trigger {

    var continue = true
    val itr = events.iterator

    // While it isn't broken and has another event
    while (continue && itr.hasNext) {
      // Assign the return value to continue
      continue = itr.next.trigger
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thta's exactly what I'm not trying to achieve. I'm looking for a way to add events in any order and define their priority in the add function.

I'm also not really keen on making more classes, e.g. FilterChain. It should be simple :P

Comment: The problem with making it priority based which has priority over things with the same priority? To clarify, which ones should execute or should they all execute no matter what when multiple events have the same priority? This ambiguity is removed with the idea of a chain, as the priority is defined by the ordering of elements in the chain. Also, you can add more insert methods (by index or id of an event) so that you can have no dependence on order in which they're added, but their relative relation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a pub/sub type class, that will aggregate all the subscriptions, along with a priority, and then publish each event by priority, so rather than subscribing to the object itself, you'd subscribe to the manager class

Answer (score 0):

A co-worker suggested the following:

```
object = new Object();
object.bind("my_trigger", function()  { print "hello"; });
object.bind("my_trigger", function()  { print "hello2"; return false; }, { priority : 10 });
object.trigger("my_trigger");
```

Upon binding, I order my events based on the priority and execute them in serial until one of them returns false and stops the execution.